# Django MEDIA not accessible

Tags: python, django

My Django app is unable to see MEDIA directory. When I run one of my views I need to open a file. The scenario is to:

1. take a record with requested id from data base
2. get the file path to a file
3. send the file to external server for OCR purposes

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    #my urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Homework( models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = None)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_scans/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    latex = models.TextField(default = "No LaTeX Here")
```

**settings.py**:

```
from pathlib import Path
from django.conf.urls.static import static

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

...

DEBUG = True

...

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

**views.py**

```
import requests
import json
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Homework

def create_homework(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #some GET stuff
    if request.method == 'POST':
        homework = Homework()
        homework.title = title
        homework.image = image
        homework.author = author
        homework.save()
        id = homework.id
        json_to_mathsnip(id)

        ....

def json_to_mathsnip(id):
    homework = get_object_or_404(Homework, pk=id)
    f = open(homework.image.url, "rb")

    ...
    some later stuff
    ...
```

Unfortunately I'm constantly running into an error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /homework/new 

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/user_scans/kwa.png'
```

My main concern is I can access file from  **localhost:8000/media/user_scans/kwa.png**
and from admin panel. Requested file is saved properly:

[image: file structure]

Also settings.py configuration seems to be in tact. What might be the issue?

```
(env) $ pip freeze
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
Django==4.0.1
idna==3.3
Pillow==9.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
requests==2.27.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.9
```

Comment: Do you have this in your root urls, `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`?  Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Updated. Yes, it's included in urls.py

Comment: What will `print(homework.image.url)` show before opening the file?

Comment: `print(homework.image.url)` outputs `/media/user_scans/kwa.png`

Comment: go to admin page and try to add a new image by admin and see what is the image URL you will get

Comment: Most likely he will just get `localhost:8000/media/user_scans/kwa.png`, @AbdelhamedAbdin, just like I should have realized that `print(homework.image.url)` would print exactly what was in the error message.  A good idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but I tried it and it works.  The bottom line is that when using the `open()` function with a relative path, such as `/media/user_scans/kwa.png`, then that file must be in the same directory as where the function is called.  You could just find the absolute path of your image files in your computer, then append the filename to that and it will work, or you can do what I have below.

```py
import requests
import json
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Homework

# ADD THESE
import os
from pathlib import Path

def create_homework(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #some GET stuff
    if request.method == 'POST':
        homework = Homework()
        homework.title = title
        homework.image = image
        homework.author = author
        homework.save()
        id = homework.id
        json_to_mathsnip(id)

        ....

def json_to_mathsnip(id):
    homework = get_object_or_404(Homework, pk=id)
    # ADD THESE
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    path_to_image_file = str(BASE_DIR) + homework.image.url
    f = open(path_to_image_file, "rb")

    ...
    some later stuff
    ...
```

When you show an image in Django, or you access its url, it is a relative path, but the root is the url root, `localhost:8000/`, and the image url is appended to that, and Django manages to find the file (how exactly, I don't know). But the image file is in your computer, and that is what you want to open.